# Send Cloud9 passwords securely when self-hosting

Tags: password-protection, cloud9-ide, self-hosting, insecure-connection

I host a [Cloud9 server](https://cloud9-sdk.readme.io), and I connect currently by tunneling via ssh to said server in order to make the login protected, yet this kind of defeats the purpose of specifying the login credentials (since I need to add the ssh keys for access anyways). I want to be able to open a port directly to the Cloud9 server, but I don't want to be sending cleartext passwords over the internet.

Is there a way to login to Cloud9 SDK without simple HTTP authentication?

Answer (score 0):

In order to skip simple HTTP authentication, please pass the command-line argument `-a :` when running the SDK version.

Comment: Is this type of verification not cleartext? On all browsers I've tested, it's said "The password will be sent unencrypted." I believe the `-a` option simply sends a cleartext login. From the command help: `--auth ... Basic Auth username:password `

Comment: Sorry, the correct argument should be `-a :` which removes the password requirement. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Oh, that's not my question - I mean how to send that password as non-cleartext.

Comment: Hmm, `Is there a way to login to Cloud9 SDK without simple HTTP authentication?` is the one I answered. In order to use a different security measure, you may need to develop a layer in front of the SDK to control access to it. Maybe a VPN or such.